# JLabels into JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am new to JAVA and need help on the following code. I have written two classes. In one I have JFrame declared and in the other the JLabel. I would like to add the Label to the Frame by this method, but I am getting an error. What changes should I do to make it work:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Label into Frame");
        Frame f1 = new Frame();
        f1.displayFrame.add(l1);
        f1.displayFrame();      
    }   
}

class Frame {

    void displayFrame() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about your error? (Compile-time vs runtime, logic error vs exception)

Comment: I would skip UI programming and start with some basic "Hello world" applications in Java / any other OO programming language

Comment: yes learn to use GUI programming with java this website will be good start for you http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/

Answer (score 3):

You can't create it like this. If you want to build a custom frame class you'll have to define it like

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame
```

to get all the JFrame methods and such. And in your code above you make a call to `displayFrame` and then on top of that you're trying to call a method `add`, this isn't going to work. To make it work (in the most simplest form) try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Label into Frame");
    JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
    f1.setSize(100, 100);
    f1.add(l1);
    f1.setVisible(true);
}
```

I suggest you try and read a few good java tutorials to learn about the basics.

Comment: The most simple and correct way imo would be to call it on the EDT instead of on the main thread, and use `f1.pack()` instead of manually setting a size. And perhaps even adding a close operation on the frame as well.

Answer (score 0):

**-** Its always good to keep the `UI` work on the `UI` thread, and `Non-UI` work on the `Non-UI` thread.

**-** Now In Java GUI applications, the `main()` method is **not long lived**, after scheduling the construction of GUI in the `Event Dispatcher Thread`, it
      quits, now its EDT's responsibility to handle the GUI.

**- Don't directly place** the `JLable` on the `JFrame`, try using a `JPanel` on the `JFrame` and then place a `JLable` on it.

**-** But just to keep it **simple** i will **not use** JPanel over here.

**Eg:**

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JLabel l1;

    public MyFrame() {

        this.setSize(400,400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setComponent();
        setHandling();

    }   

    public void setComponent(){

    l1 = new JLabel("Label into Frame");
    this.add(l1);

    }

    public void setHandling(){

      // Use this to handle the Events on the EventSources.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

       EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

         MyFrame frame = new MyFrame("Test");
        frame.setVisible(true);

       });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method displayFrame does not return anything

```
void displayFrame() {...}
```

Method decelerating follows the pattern of *{accessibility} [type] [name({parameter {, parameter ...}})]*

*Accessibility* defines who can access the method and includes, `public`, `protected` and `private` or `package-private`

*Type* refers to the type of value that this method will return. A special type of `void` states that the method will not return a value

*Name* is the name of the method, this is how you identify the method and access it

*Parameter(s)* are any number of optional values you want to pass to the method.

Armed with this information, lets take a closer look at that method.

```
void displayFrame() {...}
```

This is saying that the method is *package-private* (this means that the method is only accessible from with in the same package, but is not extendable by sub classes) and will return nothing.

```
f1.displayFrame.add(l1);
```

So when you call this method Java can't figure out how to apply `ad(...)` to nothing, it makes no sense.

A better solution would be to either provide a *getter* method to get the frame or return the frame from the *displayFrame* method. There's good arguments for either, but I personally prefer *getters*

```
public class test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Label into Frame");
        Frame f1 = new Frame();
        JFRame myFrame = f1.getFrame();
        myFrame.add(l1);
        f1.displayFrame(); // there's actually no need for this 
    }   
}

class Frame {
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    void displayFrame() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

I would take the time to have a read through [Learning the Java Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html)